# Just installed new command (pcre), it doesn't show up, but man shows manual?

Tags: unix

I just installed PCRE with Brew and don't see the pcre command. However, "man pcre" DOES show the pcre manual. Weird. Any idea what I could check?

```
Js-MacBook-Pro:~ j$ man pcre
Js-MacBook-Pro:~ j$ pcre -h
-bash: pcre: command not found
Js-MacBook-Pro:~ j$ which pcre
Js-MacBook-Pro:~ j$
```

Comment: Maybe this link will help. It might not be in your PATH variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963143/nginx-install-on-mac-os-x-lion-cannot-find-pcre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If memory serves PCRE is a library, not a command line tool.